# what does means #+keyword: means in org buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

in emacs org mode, I saw #+ prefix many times. I think this is like option but I don't know what it is. I have tried to know them, I have been googling, but I couldn't find any good document. anybody know these symbol? is this org macros?

Comment: Most such questions can be answered by reading the manual. In Emacs, say `C-h i g(org)` to get to it. Emacs provides many ways to search for things in its manuals. You should spend some time and become proficient with those facilities. The package that is used for manual reading and searching is called `Info` and you can start by using Emacs to read **its** manual: `C-h i g(info)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just plain text that you write in an org mode file. It may have two different functions:

1.- If you write it at the beginning of the file, it serves as a metadata descriptor or to include options for the file [1]. For example:

```
#+TITLE: This is the title of this file
#+AUTHOR: Loretta
#+DATE: 2022-10-15
#+STARTUP: content <--- option for displaying the contents
#+OPTIONS: H:3 toc:nil \n:nil @:t ::t |:t <--- different export options
```

2.- To create a block inside the file. This block may be code meant to be executed [2], a quotation, a comment, etc:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(+ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
#+end_src

#+begin_comment
Check the following paragraph. I am not really sure if it
has taken into account all the variables.
#+end_comment
```

[1] See https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-Settings.html for buffer settings and https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html for export settings.

[2] See https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html for code blocks.

Comment: As a minor nit, even though things like `#+TITLE:` usually are placed at the top of the file, they are equally effective if placed at the bottom or anywhere else (although it is good practice to keep them at the top where they are easy to find).  Also, the reference for code blocks is wrong: you are pointing to the `Literal Examples` section: you should be pointing to the `Working with Source code` chapter.

Comment: I pointed to the literal examples as it is easier to understand how it works. The link I used is clearer than the `Working with Source Code` one. Just for any one to compare: https://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-Source-Code.html